# How to create table names without quotes using Liquibase and Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am running a changelog script against Postgres,

```
<createTable tableName="FREE_ME_FROM_THE_QUOTES">
    <column name="ID" type="NUMERIC">
        <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
    </column>
...
```

but for some unknown reason the table name is always created in this format `public."FREE_ME_FROM_THE_QUOTES"`, I have tried to use `objectQuotingStrategy`, but the result is always the same.

Is there a way to create tables (using Liquibase) with a name that does not include quotation marks?

Something like `public.FREE_ME_FROM_THE_QUOTES`, just to be clear.

Comment: I don't know liquibase, but I think you should try `tableName="free_me_from_the_quotes"`

Comment: @Jeremy I tried, but the name is always quoted

Comment: `public.FREE_ME_FROM_THE_QUOTES` will never be, because a name which contains any uppercase characters must *always* be quoted.

Comment: @404 Because of Postgres or Liquibase?

Comment: @PampaNello: that's Liquibase which does that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, because your name contains upper-letter characters.

If you create your tables with `<createTable tableName="free_me_from_the_quotes">` then you will create a case-insensitive table.
Then, all the following selects will work:

- select * from Free_Me_From_the_Quotes
- select * from free_me_from_the_quotes
- SELECT * FROM FREE_ME_FROM_THE_QUOTES

If you are using with hibernate, for example, this is the best approach.